# Java Applet, repaint 60times/sec method and polygons

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I have run method which repaints 60times/sec and i have paint method with 4polygons in it. Also 4 buttons. when you press 1st, then poligons will range in order that red one will be on the top, when you press 2nd button polygons swop and then green is on the top and others behind it. On eclipse all good and working, but when I run it in terminal applet viewer, then polygons not stoping and refreshing constantly. How could I make like a statement that repaint everything 60time/sec but polygon only once when clicked on button.

```
public void run() {
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double ns = 1000000000.0 / 1.0;
    double delta = 0;
    requestFocus();
    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            delta--;
            update();
            repaint();
            validate();

        }
    }
}
```

and paint method

```
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            // gives sharper graphics
            g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            windows.drawRact(new Color(0xa0, 0xd1, 0xe3), g2);
    if (mlistener.firstWin) {

                add(analisysBtn);
                add(button_1);
                add(LoadFileButton);
                ifFirst = true;
                ifFirst2 = true;
                ifFirst3 = true;

                test2 = 0;
                test3 = 0;
                test4 = 0;
                windows.drawCompareWindow(g2);
                windows.drawFourthWindow(g2);
                windows.drawThirdWindow(g2);
                windows.drawSecondWindow(g2);
                windows.drawFirstWindow(g2);
}
    }
```

Comment: windows.drawCompareWindow(g2);
                windows.drawFourthWindow(g2);
                windows.drawThirdWindow(g2);
                windows.drawSecondWindow(g2);
                windows.drawFirstWindow(g2); those are polygons

Answer (score 1):

You are adding components to a GUI from within a `paint(Graphics g)` method, something you should **never** do. This method gets called repeatedly, many times outside of your control, and it needs to be blazing fast. So no program logic, no GUI structural change, and no long-running code should go in it.

As an aside, you'll be far better off using Swing and overriding the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of a JPanel rather than overriding paint directly in a top-level window.

Also you should always remember to call the super's method inside of your override, often as the first method call, to allow the component to do its housekeeping drawing.

Also, I would use a Swing Timer and not a `while (true)` loop to run my animation loop.

Comment: I will have to look deeper to it. The problem is this is my java assessment work and i already submitted it in best case i will have chance to change or add few lines... I did not know that its gonna display differently from eclipse in terminal and apparently that how they gonna run it. Is any quick solution in my case? everything rest look working except these polygons.

Comment: @user3185161: without running code, it's hard to say what's wrong.